# changing number value from pixels to perctange

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this audio player within Wordpress.  One aspect of the player is the song length playbar. It is a light grey bar, then the actual length of the current song playing is shown with another bar.  So say the length of a song is 2 minutes. If the song has played half way through (1 minute) then the current song length bar will be half of the total length bar. Sounds simple to me!

Well here is where my problem lies.. by default the total song length bar is 180px, and this is set in a jquery / javascript minifed code, not CSS or anytihng like that. Here is some of the minifed code.

```
a.fn.fullwidthAudioPlayer.defaults,t),u,x,n,m, r,q=null,B,s,X,y=0,P=-1,K=180,Q=50,k=-1,C=100,
D,F,M=!1,G=!1,L=!1,R=!1,J=!1,E=!1,S="d2be7a47322c293cdaffc039a26e05d1",j=[];
a.fullwidthAudioPlayer.play=function(){0<j.length&&(s.playState?s.resume()
:s.play(),m.find("#fap-play-pause")
```

`k=180` sets the width for the total length bar, I know this because I have changed the value from 180 to 80 and then the bar goes from 180px to 80px.

This all works great, but I would like the length bar to be a percentage, not pixels. I've tried the obvious `k=80%` but this simply broke my code.

So how would I make the audio length bar 80% instead of 180px or in other words change the value of "k" into a percentage and not pixels.

Comment: Can you just write your own javascript to modify the width after the player has loaded?

Comment: @maxedison it would only work if it was done through the minifed code, I don't really know how to do it within the minifed code though :(

Comment: Why would it only work if done through the minified code? Why can't you modify the DOM element after the player loads using your own JavaScript?